# Why struts2 html table generates one extra <tr></tr>

Tags: java, html, struts2

Code in jsp

```jsp
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Continent</th>
            <th>Independence Year</th>
            <th>Head Of State</th>
            <th>Capital</th>
            <th>Added/Edited by</th>
            <th>Time of Edit</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
          <s:iterator  value="list">  
            <tr>
                <td><s:property value="Code"/></td>  
                <td><s:property value="Name"/></td> 
                <td><s:property value="Continent"/></td> 
                <td><s:property value="IndepYear"/></td> 
                <td><s:property value="HeadOfState"/></td> 
                <td><s:property value="Capital"/></td> 
                <td><s:property value="editedbyuser"/></td> 
                <td><s:property value="editdatetime"/></td> 
                <td>
                    <s:a action="editworld">
                        edit<s:param name="Code" value="Code"/>
                    </s:a>
                </td>
            <tr>
          </s:iterator> 
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Generated HTML(only for one row)

```jsp
<tr>
  <td>ABW</td>
  <td>Aruba</td>
  <td>North America</td>
  <td>Unknown</td>
  <td>Beatrix</td>
  <td>Oranjestad</td>
  <td>Unedited</td>
  <td>Unedited</td>
  <td>
    <a href="/Struts2Login/editworld.action?Code=ABW">edit</a>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr> </tr>
```

In the last line above that `<tr></tr>` is an extra row .I am unable to understand how is this generated.Each time this `<tr></tr>` is generated after each actual row.please help me out.

Comment: you have an empty element in the list?

Comment: no. I have checked that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first close
`<tr>
          </s:iterator>` that is open in last where it shold close

try this

```
<s:if test="%{list!=null"}>
<s:iterator  value="list"> 
         <tr>
                <td><s:property value="Code"/></td>  
                <td><s:property value="Name"/></td> 
                <td><s:property value="Continent"/></td> 
                <td><s:property value="IndepYear"/></td> 
                <td><s:property value="HeadOfState"/></td> 
                <td><s:property value="Capital"/></td> 
                <td><s:property value="editedbyuser"/></td> 
                <td><s:property value="editdatetime"/></td> 
                <td>
                    <s:a action="editworld">
                        edit<s:param name="Code" value="Code"/>
                    </s:a>
                </td>
            <tr>
          </s:iterator> 
</s:if>
```

Comment: replace <tr> in last that is opening with </tr>